# Regex match specified number of words in string

Tags: regex

Is there an option in regex to tell how many from passed words in match must find ?
I have regex:

```
/\b(brasserie|desbrosses)\b/
```

and string:

```
"brasserie desbrosses"
```

Now this regex find me two match, but i want to tell him how many words should it match to return positive result. So if i tell him return me positive match for 2 words and i will have string:
"brasserie villa"
it shouldn't return me positive match, because only one word match regex. So is there an option to do this ? and of course for other number of words, like 3, 4...

Comment: i'm sorry but why i got -1 for this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(\b(?:brasserie|desbrosses)\b\s*){2}
```

to force match to succeed with at least 2 matches of given *match words*.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iM0yB0/1)